# How To Showcase High Quality Images On WordPress Website?

Tags: images

I'm building a site to showcase high quality images. I know WordPress does image compression and scaling but I want the original to be shown on the site and I also want to allow persons to download the original high quality image.

So, should I disable scaling and compression on WordPress to build this site?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: can you edit your question to make it a singular specific question? This isn't a discussion forum and this looks very broad and open ended. Keep in mind that WP doesn't modify the images you upload, it creates additional new images for each size, e.g. thumbnail/medium/large, but the original is always kept untouched as the `full` size

Comment: About disabling scaling and compression: WordPress, as I understand it, doesn't compress or scale the original uploaded WordPress file. So you are OK on that front — you just have to serve it to the user, perhaps using `wp_get_attachment_url()`. I'm not sure if this is still true over certain sizes — you might also find this article on large image downscaling helpful: https://darkog.com/blog/how-to-disable-wordpress-5-3-image-downscaling-feature

Comment: @Nabha Cosley

Ahhhh I see. So the original image I uploaded is saved. But is the original image saved as "full"? or is the new scaled image saved as "full"? I'm asking because in Elementor I can choose the image size and if I want to display the original image what do I select.

I read the blog post but it was clear as to where the original saved image is.

Comment: You know, I am not 100% sure. But there is an easy way to test — upload an extremely large image, post it using Elementor with the 'full' option, then compare file sizes to the original. If it's been downscaled, you can follow that article's instructions on disabling it. I'd love to know what you find out.